# Angular CLI error: Cannot resolve type entity i11.LayoutModule to symbol

Tags: angular, angular-cli

When running `ng serve`, this error is showing up in the console:

```
Generating browser application bundles (phase: setup)...D:\somefolder\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\reflection\src\typescript.js:482
            throw new Error("Cannot resolve type entity " + type.getText() + " to symbol");
                  ^

Error: Cannot resolve type entity i11.LayoutModule to symbol
    at Object.reflectTypeEntityToDeclaration (D:\somefolder\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\reflection\src\typescript.js:482:19)        
    at D:\somefolder\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\metadata\src\util.js:34:35
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Object.extractReferencesFromType (D:\somefolder\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\metadata\src\util.js:29:29)
    at DtsMetadataReader.getNgModuleMetadata (D:\somefolder\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\metadata\src\dts.js:62:33)
    at MetadataDtsModuleScopeResolver.resolve (D:\somefolder\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\scope\src\dependency.js:61:43)
    at LocalModuleScopeRegistry.getExportedScope (D:\somefolder\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\scope\src\local.js:515:51)
    at LocalModuleScopeRegistry.getScopeOfModuleReference (D:\somefolder\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\scope\src\local.js:257:44)     
    at LocalModuleScopeRegistry.getScopeOfModule (D:\somefolder\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\scope\src\local.js:148:22)
    at LocalModuleScopeRegistry.getScopeForComponent (D:\somefolder\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\scope\src\local.js:122:22)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure that @angular/material is installed.

Installing material fixed the issue for me.